# Determine whether $x^x$ function is injective or surjective $?$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, exponential-function

Let $f$ be a functions from $\mathbb{R^+}$ to $\mathbb{R^+}$ defined by $f(x)=x^x$

Determine whether the function $f$ injective or surjective ?

I saw here similar questions regarding this function but this differ from other problem, I will tell you what I tried

**Attempt:**

$\underline{Surjective}$

for $f(x) \in \mathbb{R^+}, $ no element $x \in \mathbb{R^+} $ such that $f(x)=0 \Rightarrow x^x=0$

Thus $f$ is not onto

I have no idea how to prove it or disprove it as a surjective,
Actually this problem is very strange to me, I referred this problem [How can we describe the graph of $x^x$ for negative values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/695701/805838) then I thought my problem would be wrong,
Any help would be greatly appreciated regarding this problem.

Comment: For injectivity...what's $f(0)$?  what's $f(1)$?

Comment: is $f(0)=0^0$ undefined?

Comment: @lulu I tried to use it but I saw somewhere $f(0)=0^0$ is undefined

Comment: Ok, so then argue that $x^x$ approaches $1$ from below if $x$ approaches $0$ from the right or if $x$ approaches $1$ from the left.

Comment: @lulu got it. is there any easy method?

Comment: Take the derivative, show the function has a local min (that's the approach the posted solutions take).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111569/discussion-between-akalanka-and-lulu).

Comment: It cannot be surjective because $f (x)\gt 0$ and it is not injective because the derivative vanishes at a point $x_0$ between $0$ and $1$ then $f$ has an extreme at $x_0$ (it is not hard to verify this and that in effect a minimum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x^x)'=\left(e^{x\ln{x}}\right)'=x^x(\ln{x}+1),$$ which says $f$ is injective on $[\frac{1}{e},+\infty)$ and on $(0,\frac{1}{e}]$.

By the way, $f$ is a surjection $$f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\left[\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{e}}},+\infty\right)$$

Comment: can you please explain this?

Comment: @Akalanka Which step?

Comment: I am not familiar  with this method can you please tell what is the method that you used?

Comment: @Akalanka I find where $f$ increase and where $f$ decreases, which gave the minimum point: $\left(\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{e}}}\right)$. All these gives when $f$ is injective. Also, we see when $f$ is a surjection.

Comment: but there is a comment $f(x)$ is surjective

Comment: @Akalanka See a last part of my post.

Comment: got it. I will try to undestand this. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

One can see that it's not injective since $f(1/2)=(1/2)^{1/2}=1/\sqrt{2}=(1/4)^{1/4}=f(1/4)$

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x) = x^x (\ln(x)+1)$. So attains a maximum or minimum at $e^{-1}$. Then you have equal values of $f$ for some 2 numbers $x,y$ where $x<e^{-1}$ and $y>e^{-1}$. This means $f$ is not 1-1 on the positive reals.