# $y=x^x$ Graph Confusion

Tags: graphing-functions

I plotted $y=x^x$ just for fun online, but i cam up with very confusing and unexpected results. The returned graph resembles a form of exponential, but with some unique features. They are the reasons why i'm confused. Graphs seem to be able to graph positive $x$-axis perfectly, but the negative $x$-axis is empty, which seems strange. Surely $(-1)^{-1}$ can be figured out right? So what is stopping the graph completing the whole thing?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: May be the website computes $x^x$ by $e^{x\ln x}$.

Comment: $(-1)^{-1}$ is "easier" to compute than $(-0.5)^{-0.5}$ since the latter requires the introduction of complex numbers. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: The resemblence to $\exp(x)$ originiates from the scaling of the graph ($e^x$ looks like $1+x$ near $0$). Try to plot it side by side and you'll notice an astnoshing difference.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394110/can-the-graph-of-xx-have-a-real-valued-plot-below-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plotter can't plot complex valued functions. $(-n)^{-n}$ can obviously be figured out in the reals, but for every other $x\in \mathbb{R^-}$ the expression evaluates to a complex number, eg. for $x = -\frac 1 2$ we have ${(-\frac 1 2 })^{- \frac 1 2} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{-\frac 1 2}}= -i\sqrt{2}$.

Wolfram Alpha, for example, can plot the correct graph, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=plot%20x%5Ex).