# Limit of a implicit function

Tags: analysis, limits, logarithms

Find the limit of the given function
$$\lim:\lim_{x\to 0} x^x$$
Does the function has limit.

I think no but how to prove it.

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090112034044AA71yQ3

Comment: I think the limit exists and it is $1$. However, as one can observer, the $x^x$ is not real when $x<0$, so probably one has to use a little bit knowledge in complex analysis to consider $e^{x \log x}$ (honestly I am not 100% sure, since I took complex analysis a while ago, feel free to correct me). In that case, with the use of L'Hôpital's rule, one can prove the limit is $1$.

Comment: The limit exists from the other side too: if you take $y = -x$, then as y->0^+ it's $\exp(-y(\log(y) +i\pi))$ which still goes to 1. More generally, it exists along any complex direction into the origin.

Comment: Look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394110/can-the-graph-of-xx-have-a-real-valued-plot-below-zero

Comment: This is not abstract algebra

Comment: and neither implicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x^x
$$
does not exist, but the one-sided limit does
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x
&=\exp\left(\lim_{\,x\to0^+}\frac{\log(x)}{1/x}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{\,x\to0^+}\frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\exp(0)\\[9pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you consider  $$y=x^x\implies \log(y)=x\log(x)\implies\lim_{x\to 0} \log(y)=0\implies \lim_{x\to 0}y=1$$

You could also, as  k99731 commented, use $y=e^{x\log(x)}$ and use Taylor series to get $$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n\log^n(x)}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n\log^n(x)}{n!}$$ remembering that $\lim_{x\to 0} x\log(x)=0$

Comment: as  x is a function you cannot do this before defining it

Answer (score 0):

If $y = 1/x$,
then
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x
=\lim_{y \to \infty} (1/y)^{1/y}
=\lim_{y \to \infty} \dfrac1{y^{1/y}}
$

But, as is well known,
and has been proved here often,
$\lim_{y \to \infty} y^{1/y}
=1
$
so that
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x
=1
$.

Comment: the well known prove you did requires some definitions of y that it can nither be positive nor negative