# Compute $\lim\limits_{x\to - \infty} x^x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to compute 
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to - \infty} x^x?
$$

**My thoughts**：

This is an $\infty^{\infty} $ indeterminate form, but I don't know how to approach it. I have thought about writing $x^x$ as $e^{x\ln x} $, but the problem is that $x \to - \infty$, so I have no clue how to compute it.

**Updated context**
Edit : the symbol $x$ is an integer. Thanks for pointing out that otherwise the function doesn't take real values.

Comment: x cant tend to -infi. its out of domain.

Comment: What is $(-\pi)^{-\pi}$ equal to?

Comment: Could we not view it as the limit of x to ∞ of $(-x)^{-x}$? Then it's just the limit of $e^{i \pi x} x^{-x}$, which would be $0$, since the first factor is bounded?

Comment: Of course, assuming we allow complex values.

Comment: It doesn't exist, unless you consider the limit over the integers.

Comment: @maveric I know it is out of $\ln$'s domain, that' s why I said my approach doesn't work. Yet, I wanted to show the people here that I had actually thought about the question before posting.

Comment: @learner why doesn't it exist?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394110/can-the-graph-of-xx-have-a-real-valued-plot-below-zero.

Comment: Because the function isn't even real for most $x$, except for the integers for which the function is real and approaches $0$ as $x\to\inf\Bbb Z$

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realised it didn't work! How about this limit over the integers? I will edit my question.

Comment: @learner thanks, I have just edited my question. Could you supply a proof for the result in your comment?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast Is $(-\pi)^\pi = \pi^\pi $ or $- \pi^\pi$? In case of odd/even integers you can clarify this, but here we have an issue.

Comment: Yes, indeed, now I see. Sorry for my initial mistake, we shall consider $x$ to be an integer from now on.

Comment: @MathEnthusiast It is good to clarify this! Note that $(-n)^{-n} = (-1)^{-n} n^{-n}$ so $|(-n)^{-n}| = |n^{-n}|$ for all $n > 0$. Now try to use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need not restrict $x$ to be an integer.  Note that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, with $x<0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
|x^x|&=\left| e^{x\log(x)}\right|\\\\
&=\left| e^{-|x|(\log(|x|)+i(2k+1)\pi)}\right|\\\\
&=\frac1{|x|^{|x|}}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the magnitude of $x^x$ approaches $0$ as $x\to -\infty$, we find that

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^x=0$$

Comment: Can you please explain your 2nd step

Comment: @MDesmond Sure.  The complex logarithm is multivalued and given by $$\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i(\arg(z)+2k\pi)$$with $\log(|z|)$ interpreted as the logarithm for real numbers and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Now for $x<0$, $x=-|x|$ and $\arg(-1)=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$.

Comment: @Mark Viola your answer is indeed very good. I actually forgot about this question, thank you for reminding me.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

If $x\ll 0$ is an integer much lower than $0$, then $x^{-1}$ is very close to $0$, and $x^x$ is even closer to $0$. So the we get a determinate form, and the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=-n$ where $n\in\Bbb N$.

$$x^x=(-n)^{-n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}$$

This is an alternating sequence with the denominator $n^n$ approaching $\infty$ as $n\to\sup\Bbb N=\infty$, so the reciprocal approaches $0$.

A more rigorous approach would be to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition though.