# Is the power of 1/2 same thing as principal square root?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

$\sqrt{9} = 3$

9 has 2 square roots: 3 and -3.

What is $9^\frac12$? Is $9^\frac12 = \sqrt{9} = 3$ or is $9^\frac12 = \pm3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a^b$ is always positive for $a\in\Bbb R^+$ and $b\in\Bbb R$.  This is because $f(x)=a^x$ satisfies the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ (i.e. $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$).  It follows that $f(2x)=f(x)^2,$ or $$a^x=f(x)=f\left(\frac x2\right)^2\ge 0$$
Consequently, $9^\frac12\ge 0\implies 9^\frac12=3$

Comment: I guess it would have to be that way because $9^1 = 9^\frac12 \cdot 9^\frac12$ and the result of that can't be negative.

Comment: No, you'll see that $(-3)(-3)=9$, so in that respect $9^\frac12$ would work.  But $9^\frac12=(9^\frac14)^2$, so $9^\frac12$ can't be negative assuming $9^\frac14$ is real-valued, which it is.

Comment: What I meant was if $9^\frac12$ could be negative or positive, then one of them could be negative and the other positive making $9^1$ negative.

Comment: We're assuming that $f(x)=9^x$ is well-defined, that is $f(x)$ is only one value for any $x$.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question I asked a couple months ago and am reviewing your answer that I accepted. I'm not as sure about your answer anymore. Basically, $9^\frac12$ can be $(9^\frac14)^2$, but that doesn't, by itself, preclude it from also being equal to -3. How do we get away from the fact that $9=(-3)^2$ and so we can replace 9 with $(-3)^2$ in $9^\frac12$?

Comment: $9^{1/4}$ is, itself, real and nonzero, right? Any real number that is not zero, when squared, is greater than zero.  Therefore $9^{1/2}=(9^{1/4})^2>0\implies 9^{1/2}=3$.

Answer (score 1):

[This previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/317546/14972) of mine talks about the fact there are actually multiple exponentiation operators. The meaning of $9^{\frac{1}{2}}$ depends on which one you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

To tell you the truth, it all depends on the given **context**, because the $n^{th}$ root of a certain number can be **any** of the *n* complex solutions to the equation $x^n=a$, so each radical is a **choice**. If your context is $\mathbb{R}$, then you look for the single real solution if *n* is odd, or for the positive one if *n* is even. But if you dabble into something a bit more serious, like $\mathbb{C}$, [cubics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), [quartics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), or [Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory), then you have to be very careful each step of the way that the values you ascribe to each of these roots fulfill certain **criteria**. For instance, **all** the various formulae for the zeroes of the cubic or quartic equations rely heavily on which choices one makes for each radical, and if these choices fail to meet certain demands, then the formulae yield **false** results. E.g., at a certain point, when $\Delta_0=0$, one has to choose the value of $\sqrt{\Delta_1^2\!-\!4\Delta_0^3}=\!\sqrt{\Delta_1^2}=\!\Delta_1$ , *even if the quantity in question is negative*, otherwise the formula simply doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

$9^\frac{1}{2}=3.$ not $-3$. This is because $9^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is positive.