# How to evaluate rational numbers to rational powers

Tags: exponentiation, rational-numbers

Is there a method besides a Taylor series to calculate $x^y$, where $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers? So for example, I require a method to calculate $2.128321\dots^{5.3212\dots}$ to a certain amount of digits. I realize that Taylor series are always an option, but is that what is used in calculators and computers? If not, what is used?

Comment: @DietrichBurde when thinking about this, I considered doing what you're describing-- finding the quotient of the rational number and taking the n-th root. But is that what is required? This will be very computationally expensive

Comment: Also, there are further problems, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582735/raising-to-rational-power-issues) and its answers. It involves using the principal value of an complex expression.

Comment: @DietrichBurde all I need is to be able to take a rational number to another rational number that are each precise to an arbitrary amount, and find the result of it. This is possible, I'm sure, but I also see the problem you've shown.

Comment: The you need to restrict to positive rational numbers, I guess.

Comment: @DietrichBurde is it only undefined when b <= 0?

Comment: $x^y = \exp(y \ln(x))$ (for $x > 0$).  There are many numerical methods for computing exponentials and logarithms.  For example, you might look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239352/how-do-pocket-calculators-calculate-exponents)

Comment: @RobertIsrael the problem is, any function like ln(x) would come back to the same problem, as the usable functions are ones I'm building from scratch (infinite floating point)