# Does $e^{-im\pi}=(-1)^m$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$m \in (0,1]$

$e^{-im\pi}=(e^{i(-\pi)})^m=(\cos(-\pi)+i\sin(-\pi))^m=(-1)^m$

Can someone confirm if this is correct?

I noticed it can be $(-1)^{-m}$ which was a bit weird.

Comment: Same thing, but $(-1)^m$ looks nicer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas it is also a bit weird how $(-1)^m \neq -1$....

Comment: Why is that wierd ? . $(-1)^2 = 1$

Comment: @Shailesh but m is not above 1. but I think I see how it is not equal to -1 now because sometimes it is not defined, for example when m=1/2.

Comment: I'm not so sure that $(-1)^m$ is a good notation when $m$ is not an integer. See here for a discussion: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/317546/169852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, try $m=\frac12$. We have $e^{-i\pi/2}=-i$, but taking the principal branch of the complex exponential, $\left(e^{-i\pi}\right)^{1/2}=(-1)^{1/2}=i$.

Comment: is there any way to simplify it?

Comment: You could fix the equation to read either $e^{im\pi}=(-1)^m$ or $e^{-im\pi}=(-1)^{-m}=1/(-1)^m$.