# $[(-2)^\frac{3}{8}]^\frac{8}{3}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, real-numbers

If we have to evaluate 
$[(-2)^\frac{3}{8}]^\frac{8}{3}$ 
would the answer be -2 or 2? My teacher says that in this case the exponents can't be multiplied as they are not natural numbers. Then how do we simplify it solving one bracket in a step?

Comment: How do you suggest to **define** $z^a$, in the first place, when $z$ is not a nonnegative real number and $a$ is not an integer?

Comment: Non-integer exponents do not make sense with negative bases. If you have this from a book or a teacher, then you shouldn't be reading that book or listening to that teacher. If you've invented this problem yourself, then the answer is "There is no solution".

Comment: so is the entire expression not defined

Comment: @user456 check this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/317546/133781

Comment: i have got $$-2$$