# Can a negative number be raised to a fractional power e.g $2.5$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, exponentiation, fractions, integers

Is it possible to raise a negative integer or other negative number to a power that is not an integer ?

I am asking because when plotting some polynomial functions the negative numbers were not plotted and I am curious why.

Why is it possible to raise $-5$ to the power of $7$ but it is not possible to raise $-5$ to the number of $7.5$ and is it also impossible to plot the function $x^{7.5}$ ?

Comment: It will be discontinuous at infinite points in any finite interval. $(-5)^{7.5}$ would mean $(\sqrt{-5})^{15}$

Comment: The function $x \mapsto x^a$ is only a polynomial if $a$ is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: @Travis  I did not knew that. Can you point me to an explanation of this concept ?

Comment: Its the definition of polynomials.

Comment: There is no explanation --- by definition a polynomial is sums of positive integer powers. Yoyo --- what is $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you compute negative numbers to fractional powers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers)

Comment: This is just the definition of polynomial. The function $x \mapsto B x^a$ is called a *power function*.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy it is the complex number i

Comment: So if the a can take values in a continuous interval it is considered a power function as opposed to a polynomial function ?

Answer (score 1):

$(-5)^{7.5}$ is not a real number. This is because if $x=(-5)^{7.5}$, that would imply $x^2=(-5)^{15}=-(5^{15}),$ which is not possible for $x$ real, since squares of real numbers cannot be negative.

You can raise a negative number to some fractional powers and get a real number answer, but only if the denominator of the fraction (in its lowest terms) is odd. For example, if you wanted $x=(-5)^{7/3}$, you would need $x^3=(-5)^7=-5^7$. This is possible, because cubes can be negative, and you just get $-(5^{7/3})$.

It does make sense to talk about $(-5)^{7.5}$ as an imaginary number, but since it's not real you can't plot it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you can.

However, to do so requires working with complex numbers and a definition of the principal $\alpha$th power is

$$ z^\alpha = e^{\alpha\ \text{Log}\ z}$$

where $z, \alpha \in \mathbb C$, and $z \ne 0$

Obviously you will run in to problems when wanting to plot graphs of real functions if the answer is complex valued.