# Restrictions adding exponent laws

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation, radicals

Alright, so i want to add restrictions to this list of exponent laws. The code i will post now is **my attempt at writing their restrictions and the laws i want to write restrictions on. SO, please let me know if my attempt is correct and if it's not i would like to see how to write them correctly.**

For all $\mathbf{a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}}$, for all $\mathbf{d,d'\neq 0}$
$$d^b\cdot d^c=d^{b+c}$$
$$(d^b)^c=d^{bc}$$
$$(d \cdot d')^c=d^cd'^c$$
$$\left(\frac{d'}{d}\right)^b=\frac{d'^b}{d^b}$$
$$\frac{d^a}{d^b}=d^{a-b}$$
$$d^{-a}=\frac{1}{d^a}$$
$$a^{\frac{b}{d}}=\begin{cases} \sqrt[d]{a^b} & \text{if d is odd}\\ \sqrt[d]{a^b}, & a\geq 0, \text{if d is even} \end{cases}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{ab}=\sqrt[d]{a}\sqrt[d]{b},\quad\text{where} \textbf{ both } \text{a and b are non-negative}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{\frac{a}{d'}}=\frac{\sqrt[d]{a}}{\sqrt[d]{d'}},\quad\text{where} \textbf{ both } \text{a and d' are non-negative}$$
$$\sqrt[d]{\sqrt[d']{a}}=\sqrt[dd']{a}$$

Comment: How would you fix that? I'm having trouble understanding what you say. Also should i just remove the even and odd cases? I think they are redundant

Comment: I think it might be better if i just link to this other SE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers

Comment: hmm, no that does not clarify my question

Comment: uhmmm, i still need help