# $E(\frac{1}{X^\epsilon})$ when $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and $\epsilon>1$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

I know that the [reciprocal normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution) does not have a defined mean or variance. But I wonder whether it is possible to get an expression for the mean when raising the reciprocal to a power greater than 1. As I understand it, the mean of the reciprocal normal does not exist because the tails are too heavy for the integral to be evaluated. Intuitively, I think that raising the reciprocal to a power greater than 1 would put less weight on the tails when evaluating the integral, and therefore potentially make the integral converge. In particular, I am looking at $\epsilon \approx 1.5$, in case the particular value of $\epsilon$ makes a difference. As I understand it, the question is whether the following integral can be solved:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^\epsilon \sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2} \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: In the case that $\mu=0$ this can be evaluated in terms of the Gamma function, using the well known Mellin transform of the Gaussian
$$\int_{\mathbb R}x^{s-1}\exp(-x^2/2)\mathrm dx=2^{-1+s/2}(1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \pi s})\Gamma(s/2) \\ \Re(s)>0$$
But if $\mu\neq 0 $ it's not so simple, and can only be written in terms of special functions (hypergeometrics).

Comment: If $Y=(1/X)^\epsilon$,  then to get less heavy tails I think you need to use smaller $\epsilon$, not greater.

Answer (score 1):

Notice first that $x^\epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and negative real $x$ is [not very well defined (or at least is tricky)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers).

If we consider instead $Y=1/|X|^{\epsilon}$. For large $y$, we have

$$P(Y>y)=P(|X| < y^{\beta}) \approx \gamma \, y^{\beta} $$

with $\beta = -1/\epsilon$ and $\gamma = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi \sigma^2}}\exp{(-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2})} $ which implies

$$f_Y(y) \approx  \gamma \beta\, y^{\beta-1}$$

In order to have a finite variance, we need $1-\beta > 3$, or $\epsilon <1/2$